# Limpar diretório pra depois criar galeria dentro dele usando php

Tags: php, galeria, edição-de-imagens

Boa tarde, estou criando um arquivo que edita a postagem dos produtos, só que  antes de editar os dados e inserir os novos que o cliente selecionou .. era pra ele apagar as fotos do diretório onde a galeria de imagens foi criada, gostaria de ajuda de vcs, segue o código comentado.

```
    <?php
// Incluir o arquivo conecta.php que faz a conexão com o banco de dados
include "conecta.php" ;
$Nomediretorio = $_POST['titulo'];

//apagando os dados antes de iniciar a edição

function apaga_files($name)
{
  $dir = 'foto_produtos/galeria/'.$Nomediretorio;
  if(is_dir($dir))
  {
    if($handle = opendir($dir))
    {
      while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== false)
      {
        if($file != '.' && $file != '..')
        {
          if( $file != $name)
          {
            unlink($dir.$file);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    die("Erro ao abrir dir: $dir");
  }
        return 0;
}

//inicia a edição

$id = $_POST['i'];
$imagem = $_FILES['imagem'];

//pega extenção da imagem

preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg|){1}$/i",$imagem['name'], $ext);

$nome_imagem = md5(uniqid(time())) . ".". $ext[1];

$caminho_imagem = "foto_produtos/".$nome_imagem;

move_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'], $caminho_imagem);


$sql = "UPDATE portifolio SET imagem = '".$nome_imagem."', titulo = '".$_POST['titulo']."' ,
 descricao = '".$_POST['descricao']."', marca = '".$_POST['marca']."',
 referencia = '".$_POST['referencia']."', preco = '".$_POST['preco']."', destaque = '".$_POST['destaque']."',
 ativa = '".$_POST['ativa']."', data = now() WHERE id = $id";
$query =  mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

//Retorno a página de formulário
echo "
 <script language='javascript'>
 alert('Dados editados com sucesso!');
 parent.location='portifolio_adm.php';
     </script>
";
?>
```

Comment: boas esta a tentar um apagar directório?

Comment: Não quero apenas limpar os arquivos dentro dele, o resto do código funciona bem.. só a parte de limpar os aquivos

Comment: Você verificou se o diretório existe com `file_exists` dentro da função `apaga_files`?